Как выставить текст посередене в Кнопке на AndroidTV
Достаточно простая задача, мне нужно сделать кнопку которая будет иметь минимальную ширину внезависимости от того какой там текст. И так же есть максимальная ширина, то есть если текст короткий то кнопка занимает Х ширины, если текст длинее чем минимальная ширина кнопки, то кнопка растягивается, чтоб покрыть весь текст до того как упрется в максимальную свою ширину. Проблема в том, что текст при условии когда он короткий, то  есть вот такой код:
...
import androidx.tv.material3.Button  
...


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestFocusRequestTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Test2()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Test2() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.widthIn(min = 288.dp, max = 488.dp),
            onClick = { }
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier,
                text = "Short text",
                color = Color.White
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.widthIn(min = 288.dp, max = 488.dp),
            onClick = { }
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier,
                text = "!! Long long long long long long long long text !!",
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                color = Color.White
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.widthIn(min = 288.dp, max = 488.dp),
            onClick = { }
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier,
                text = "!! Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text !!",
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}

Выглядит вот так:

А нужно вот так:

На скриншоте видно, что 2я и 3я кнопка работают как и ожидается, но первая почему выставляет выравнивание текста по левому краю, а не по центру.
Есть идеи как это исправить?
P.S. Кнопка из import androidx.tv.material3.Button -> implementation("androidx.tv:tv-material:1.0.0")

у текста есть свойство  textAlign = TextAlign.Center, и задайте модифаер на максимально возможную ширину в контейнере

@DeniskaSosiSka в этом и проблема, я не могу задать максимально возможную ширину, потому что тогда кнопка займет максимально возможную ширину, то есть как на скриншоте в вопросе, вместо того, чтоб кнопка была такого размера как первая, она будет такого размера как третья. Добавил еще один скрин в вопрос

атрибуты maxWidth и minWidth не подойдут?

@Style-7 мне кажется, что это .widthIn(min = 288.dp, max = 488.dp) делает то же самое. Но вопрос в том, что текст не становиться посередине.

Свойство Gravity работает? Попробуйте выровнять вправо и т.п. На снимке текст второй и третьей кнопки длинный и по этому просто растянут на всю длину и возможно там аналогичная проблема.

@Style-7 в compose нет свойства gravity

Попробуй добавить для кнопки следующий модификаторы
textAlign = TextAlign.Center, 
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

Если проблема останется, проверь нет ли каких-то конфликтных модификаторов которые не дают выровнять кнопку по центру.

Я добавил код в вопрос, он достаточно простой, попробуй добавить то что предложил и ты поймешь в чем проблема

Добавьте в разметку кнопки это: android:gravity="center" Должно помочь

это пример для xml кода, у меня jetpack compose
